# Writing declarative configuration checks in Python?

Tags: python, xml, configuration-files

We have a collection of hand-rolled Python scripts that validate various things in our production environment/configuration.

Many of these are simple XML checks (i.e. validate that the value of this XML tag here equals the value in that file over there). Others might be to check that a host is up, or that this application's crontab start time is within 20 minutes of X, or that a logfile on a server contains a certain line.

The checks are executed automatically before each production push.

The scripts are written imperatively. E.g.:

1. SSH into a server
2. Open up a file
3. Parse the XML
4. Search for a XML tag
5. Store the value in a variable
6. Compare it to another value somewhere else.

I'd like to look at writing a framework to do these validation in a slightly more declarative way - i.e. instead of defining how the server should check something, we should just be able to say `<tag>value</tag> should equal foobar` - and let the framework handle the how.

I was thinking we could then schedule the checks and shove the jobs onto a queue like Celery.

To stop me from re-inventing the wheel - are there any existing projects that do something like this already?

Or has anybody here done something similar, or would be able to offer any advice?

(I aware of things like Puppet or Chef - or even Salt Stack - however, these are for managing deployments, or actually pushing out configurations. These validation scripts are more to ensure that the configuration changes done by hand are sane, or don't violate certain basic rules).

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've used an approach similar to the one I suggest below, for declaratively applying patches to data.

Each declarative validation-file is a python-snippet, using predefined functions, variables, etc.  Each check is a python function.  Running the validations is done using a driver script which includes a `execfile` call to run the check-files.

E.g. you can have a validation file like:

```
tag_equals('value', 'foobar')
attribute_exists('value', 'value_attr')
```

And your driver script is basically:

```
def main():
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        run_validation(filename)

def run_validation(filename):
    # import all "built-in" names for validations
    from mychecks import tag_equals, etc
    execfile(filename, locals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Advantages:

1. parsing/interpretting is trivially-easy using `execfile`
2. easy to extend capabilities (e.g.
   write a new `xpath_equals` function)
3. flexible -- in the cases you want to perform validations involving specialized logic, you can implement it in your validation-file, without having to extend the     definition of your declarative language. E.g. `for i in range(10):
   tag_equals('address%d' % i, 'N/A')`

To protect against accidentally `execfile`ing an arbitrary python file, you should add a check to only run `execfile` if the first
line in the file equals some predefined header.